# Scraping a site with mutliple pages that retain the same url?

Tags: python

I'm experimenting with webscraping for the first time in python. I'm using the beautifulsoup4 package to do so. I've seen some other people saying that you need to use a for-loop if you want to get all the data from a site with multiple pages, but in this particular case, the URL doesn't change when you go from page to page. What do I do about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated
Here's my python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get("https://wpcarey.asu.edu/people/departments/finance")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")


professors = soup.select(".view-content .views-row")

professor_names = {}

for professor in professors:
    if "Professor" in professor.select_one(".views-field.views-field-nothing-1 .field-content .title").getText() or "Lecturer" in professor.select_one(".views-field.views-field-nothing-1 .field-content .title").getText():
        if professor.select_one(".views-field.views-field-nothing-1 .field-content .name > a").getText() not in professor_names:
            professor_names[professor.select_one(".views-field.views-field-nothing-1 .field-content .name > a").getText()] = professor.select_one(".views-field.views-field-nothing .field-content .email > a").getText()

print(professor_names)
```

Believe me, I know it's hideous but it's just a draft. The main focus here is finding a way to loop through every page to retrieve the data.
Here's the first page of the site if that helps.
https://wpcarey.asu.edu/people/departments/finance
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the Button to go to the next page you see that the second page is also available under this link https://wpcarey.asu.edu/people/departments/finance?page=0%2C1 .
The third page is: https://wpcarey.asu.edu/people/departments/finance?page=0%2C2

If you use i.e. firefox you can right click on the button to go to the next page and investigate the code of the webpage.

Comment: How are you seeing these really concise url's? Sorry if that's a really noob question but when I right click on the button to copy the link address, I get a giant string query

Comment: I see the URL when moving the mouse over the button (not clicking!) [This is called hovering, then firefox shows a hint](https://www.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/firefox-link-address.png) Different browsers behave different on that.